# How to return a string (or break) from forEach loop when a condition is met

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 14. I checked [this](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/foreach-break) and several other articles but none was useful at all. I've a piece of code in a ternary operator. The code is like this:

```
var finalValue = this.recordData.myArray.length === 0
            ? 'empty record'
            : this.recordData.myArray.forEach(
                (item: any) => {
                  if (item.stockKeepingStatus == 'A') {
                    this.thing = 'found';
                    // break; // syntax error
                    return this.thing;
                  } else {
                    this.thing = 'all are inactive';
                  }
                  return this.thing;
                }
              )

console.log(finalValue);
```

The logic is simple. If `myArray` is empty, then just say 'empty record'. Otherwise we will iterate through `myArray` array and check which item has `stockKeepingStatus` as active i.e. 'A'. The moment we find our first 'A' we will just break the loop and return 'found'. If none of the`stockKeepingStatus` was 'A' then we will just say 'all are inactive'. I'm getting `finalValue` undefined. Please point out my mistake.

Comment: `forEach` returns `undefinded` thus Instead of [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) use `every()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use `find` method instead of `forEach` to return an item with `stockKeepingStatus` as 'A' or `undefined` otherwise.
This method works the way you described - checks for first entry that meets a condition and stop going through a loop if an element found, than returns a found element or return `undefined` otherwise.

```js
const finalValue = this.recordData.myArray.length === 0
    ? 'empty record'
    : (this.recordData.myArray.find(item => item.stockKeepingStatus === 'A') ?
         'found' : 'all are inactive'
      );


console.log(finalValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

`find` method returns the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function. If no values satisfy the testing function, `undefined` is returned

```
const item = this.recordData.myArray.find((item: any) => item.stockKeepingStatus == 'A');

const finalValue = this.recordData.myArray.length === 0 ? 'empty record' : item ? 'found' : 'all are inactive';

console.log(finalValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the break keyword within a forEach loop to return a string when a condition is met.

For example, let's say you want to iterate over an array of strings and return the first string that starts with the letter 'A'. You can use the following code to do this:

```
const strings = ["Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie"];

let resultString = '';

strings.forEach(string => {
  if (string.startsWith('A')) {
    resultString = string;
    break;
  }
});

console.log(resultString); // 'Alpha'
```

Comment: Error: Jump target cannot cross function boundary.ts(1107)